# leak search using instrument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm new to instrument and as soon s i start my app and load a view with image etc I'm getting to what seem leak. Double clicking the line didn't take me to the code that causes the leak and i'm not sure why or how  i'm suppose to find the appropriate code. (this is thru iOS simulator for iPhone). see attached image:

[image: instrument]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the right most button in the "View" options to display the extended detail window. This will display the stack trace for each allocation of memory. You can then double click on a line item in the stack trace which will open the source code.